# Xcode 6 device-specific asset catalog

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, asset-catalog

I'm trying to update my app for the new 6 and 6+ devices.

I've added launch images for the new iPhone sizes (6 and 6+). There are entries in the asset catalog for both the 6 and 6+. No problem there.

I also have some full-screen view overlay images that I need to add as well.  I already have images for these in @2x (iPhone 4s) and R4 (iPhone 5 5s 5c).  I've created images at the new resolution sizes, but I'm not sure how to add them into an image set.

When I go into the asset catalog, I can choose device-specific in the image set, and I see entries for iPhone, retina-4, and iPad.  There are drag/drop wells for 1x, 2x, Retina 4 2x, and 3x.

My question - where should I put the image for the iPhone 6?  Obviously the 3x is for the 6 plus.  I don't see how the retina-4 well can be used for both the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 because the screen sizes are different.

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe extend the topic for the question for Xcode 6 and above ? (see my answer to find out why I suggest it)

Answer (score 6):

I'm fairly certain that this is a bug in Xcode 6.  When you load an image from an asset catalog image set, you will always get the 3x entry for an iPhone 6+ whether you are zoomed or standard display mode.  For an iPhone 6, you will always get the 2x entry in both modes.  For an iPhone 4s, you will also get the 2x entry.

All these devices have different scaling and aspect ratios, so this is not acceptable for pixel-accurate images.  My images are all full-screen and meant to be overlays, so I was seeing incorrect placement when in zoomed mode.

I worked around this problem by creating two image sets:
**1) iPhone 6/6plus in standard mode**
     1242x2208 image in the 3x entry
      750x1334 in the 2x entry

**2)  iPhone 6/6Plus in zoomed mode or iPhone 5**
     1125x2001 for the 3x entry
      640x1136 for the 2x entry
      640x1136 for the R4-2x entry

To make this work, I then need to determine if the device is one of the new ones and if they are in zoomed mode.  Based on this information, I load the image from the correct image set.

This is the code I use to determine if the device is one of the new ones in zoomed/standard mode:

```
UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
if (screen.scale == 3 && screen.currentMode.size.width == 1242 ||
    screen.scale == 2 && screen.currentMode.size.width == 750) {
    self.overlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StdImageSet"]];
} else {
    self.overlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ZoomedImageSet"]];
}
```

This is ugly, and I hate having to do this, since image sets are supposed to eliminate this kind of code.  I haven't seen a better way around this, and I've filed a radar (radar 18463463) bug.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was pulling my hair out trying to understand why the 6+ is loading full sized images in zoom mode.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's very frustrating. What worries me is that Xcode has now been updated for the the iWatch but there's no sign of this bug being fixed. It has to be a bug, right…? I'm reporting it as one any. Hopefully they will fix this.

Answer (score 5):

I found this helpful: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Seems the iPhone 6 will use a resampled @2x (iPhone 5) image.  Also, the image set's properties (utilities pane) lets you switch between 'Universal' (x1, x2, x3) and 'Device-specific' image wells.

Comment: Yes, that is a useful explanation of how the 6+ scales.  However, I believe that doesn't answer my question.  After experimentation, I found that in Xcode 6.0.1, iPhone 6 images should go into the \@2x well. I think that this is a bug, because there is now no place to put \@2x images intended for the iPhone 4s (which is still supported in iOS8)  

Also, there is no place in the image set to put images for the display zoom modes of the iPhone 6 and 6+.

Comment: I'm building a Universal app, and my iPhone 5/5s and iPhone 6 images are both taken from the Retina 4 2x well (320x568 points), as per the explanation in the link.  This is separate from the 2x well used for the iPhone 4s.  The iPhone 6 images are upsampled to 750x1334 pixels before being rendered.

Comment: @KurtSchwartz, I stand corrected.  I double-checked after posting my comment, and the iPhone 6 is indeed using the 2x image intended for the iPhone 4s - not the one from the retina 4 2x well.  The PaintCode link appears to be wrong, and it does look like a minor bug.  However, it doesn't make much difference - either way the image is shared between the iPhone 6 (upscaled) and another model.

Comment: I've filed a radar on this. In addition to the missing drop-well for 640x960 2x images, I think that to get pixel-accurate images on a iPhone 6+ in zoom display mode, Xcode image sets need one additional drop-well for 1125x2001 3x images.  For zoom mode images on a 6, I think the retina-4 2x images should be loaded automatically when the device is in this mode.  I suspect that the 2x images are loaded instead. but I don't have a 6 and so I can't test this.

Comment: I think the PaintCode link is correct, but the UIImage loading mechanism is broken on iPhone 6. I just tried this and iPhone 6 really ignores _Retina 4_ asset version.

Comment: Looks like UIImage also can't figure out the difference between an iPad in Portrait & Landscape mode: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026105/landscape-vs-portrait-background-image-in-asset-catalog/26043767#26043767

Comment: Oh wow, good spot. It's crazy that it uses the 4/4S image size; that has to be a bug.

Comment: Is there any additional feedback regarding this issue? The only problem that I currently have with the asset catalog is for iPhone 6 - it loads the @2x image and not the supposed -568h@2x one.

Answer (score 5):

This is really annoying. For device-specific setting, we would all expect a menu like in LaunchImage Set, different placeholders for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 5):

I place here some of my observations which I did for iPhone devices (maybe someone will find it helpful):

1. iPhone 4S - `2x Any/Any` tile
2. iPhone 5 - `2x 1GB/Any` tile
3. iPhone 5S - `2x 1GB/Any` tile
4. iPhone 6 - `2x 1GB/Any` tile
5. iPhone 6 Plus - `3x 1GB/Any` tile

To achieve this I checked Devices - iPhone, Memory 1GB. As you can see there is no distinction for graphics between `iPhone 5/5S/6`. Maybe playing with settings for `Metal 1v2/2v2` could be distinguish but this looks to me like going too crazy. [Knowledge reference starts at 10:50](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=104)

What I got from WWDC right now we should think not resolution/device/device orientation specifics but focus on a size classes (which are the same for iPhones except 6 Plus) but if anyone would still, for some reasons, need that device specific graphics and wants to use asset catalogs (which are great) then here you get what I found available at the moment (`Xcode 7`).

Comment: Agree with you, it is totally weird that there is no possibility to distinguish  iPhone 5/5S/6

Answer (score 1):

Just found a new solution for this issue. Use the retina 4 image for 2x and set the full screen image view's content model to scale aspect fill will get it working on both iPhone 4s and iPhone 6.

Comment: That's not a good solution because it will kinda crop the image.