# iPhone 6 / 6+ resolution scaling for keyboard extension

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm having problems getting my images scaled right on iPhone 6 and 6+ devices.
I'm working on a custom keyboard extension, and I use an image to render the keys.

In normal mode, all is fine on all devices. In zoomed mode, it appears that I will need to add further image sets, according to this question: [Xcode 6 device-specific asset catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954706/xcode-6-device-specific-asset-catalog). This is ugly, but it seems to work well enough so far.

As an additional headache, I've come across certain apps that seem to run in even lower resolution. The LinkedIn app, for example. Even the "zoomed mode picture" seems too large and overflows the screen. It looks to be running at closer to the iPhone 5 resolution - a 960px (320*3) image renders somewhat OK on a 6+ device.

However - when I log the width of my UIImageView, it's returning 375 points both in zoomed mode and the LinkedIn app. The scale property of UIScreen also seems to be 3 at all times.

This is how I log:

```
log.debug("Height: \(self.keyboardView.bounds.height)")
log.debug("Width: \(self.keyboardView.bounds.width)")
log.debug("Screen Width: \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)")
log.debug("Screen scale: \(UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)")
log.debug("Screen native scale: \(UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale)")
```

and this is what I get:

#### Normal

LinkedIn.app

```
Height: 216.0
Width: 375.0
Screen Width: 414.0
Screen scale: 3.0
Screen native scale: 2.60869565217391
```

MobileNotes.app

```
Height: 216.0
Width: 375.0
Screen Width: 414.0
Screen scale: 3.0
Screen native scale: 2.60869565217391
```

#### Zoomed

MobileNotes

```
Height: 216.0
Width: 375.0
Screen Width: 375.0
Screen scale: 3.0
Screen native scale: 2.88
```

LinkedIn

```
Height: 216.0
Width: 375.0
Screen Width: 375.0
Screen scale: 3.0
Screen native scale: 2.88
```

Do I need to provide an extra set of images for these old apps as well - and if so, how can I detect that such an app is currently running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the way to detect this is in

```
override func updateViewConstraints()
```

where you can check the value of

```
self.view.frame.size.width
```

which will be 320 in a legacy app.

Comment: This was most helpfull thank you for sharing. I have a question about the matter: Do you know of some old "legacy app" that is still available in app store and supports landscape mode? I would like to test my "legacy mode" in landscape too. If you know what would be width of a keyboard in such legacy app in landscape that would also help. Thank you

Comment: Sorry - I didn't see this until now. Unfortunately I don't know any apps that do legacy mode in landscape. The few legacy apps I've encountered so far have (fortunately) been landscape only.