# iOS handle Layouts for ipad pro?

Tags: ios, ipad

How to handle Layouts for iPad pro as there is nothing to manage different image sizes in xcasset. also my current UI for iPad air 2 seems to b disturbed in iPad pro. any suggestions or a way to handle it?

Comment: Not sure what are you asking. Are you using autolayout & Size Classes ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do in image asset.
Both iPad and iPad Pro uses the same size classes (Regular-Regular) for both orientations and in xcasset you can identify images eventually by their size classes or major device type (iPad vs iPhone vs watch) .
The only thing you can do is provide images a little bit bigger, or fix the size of image views and, instead, make some other elements with flexible width and height, such as space between images or the elements.

As pointed by Julian is worth to mention that is possible to detect the device type at runtime by inspecting `UIDevice` class properties and select the proper image at runtime. Apple do not support those methodology.

Comment: you can be more specific for what kind of device the asset should be applied. See [similar Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32094194/3151066). Not sure if such kind of distinction can be applied here. I know that might be a bit crazy but I wanted to point out that technically it might be possible

Comment: Follow this link look at the bottom for possibilities https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingImageSets.html

Comment: this is what I'm talking about :) but there is not recipe how distinction for devices (e.g how iPhone 5S and 6 can be done). This is why I put in doubt your first sentence that I would check before if that can not be achieved in the way I have described. Have you already checked that?

Comment: @JulianKról I'm really sorry but I really do not understand what are you asking me. In image asset you can specify images for platforms (iPhone,iPad,watchOS, tvOS) or for size classes (and other options). If you try to get at runtime the device type, you can use UIDevice. That class expose some methods to get device, ios version etc, but Apple discourage those methods.

Comment: okay I will try to clarify what I'm talking about :) In assets, as you the links you included show, you can define cases for which this asset should be used. You can define that asset should be for devices with for example 2GB memory of metal version. So my thought is that might be the way to distinguish iPad air 2 from iPad pro. Although it looks like hackery from the technical point it might be possible. Is that clearer now?

Comment: Yes it's clear, but I think it's going into the opinion field. In my opinion I would never do, first because I think that memory is about metal and 3d applications to just reduce the memory pressure not detect device. Second because if Apple would allow you do that they will simply add more checkbox to the device section. In the HIG is pretty clear, think relative not about a specific device, if you are doing in the other way from the Apple perspective you are designing your app in a wrong way

Comment: Agree 120%, points you raised are right. Anyway I think it is worth mentioning that this way it might be achieved (not sure) and I would add doubts and points you made. Choice is up to the programmer... This is why I'm not sure if your first sentence is correct - that is what all of my comments are about

Comment: Hi, Guys first of all thanks for your interest in this issue. what I have got from your comments and answer is that we have to manage layout ourself. we can use subclasses, categories and autolayout to do this. changing spacings, image/button sizes which are approx. 10% bigger than normal ipad size. on behalf of screen width/height need to maintain aspect ratios. font sizes may be maintained by creating subclasses of ui components like UIabel, UIbutton etc for both ipad and pro. any further suggestions are welcome :)